# Sniffer with libpcap on Mac OS X in C

Tags: c, pcap, packet-sniffers

I was trying to create my own sniffer (ONLY FOR FUN), and I work on a Mac.
I'm using libpcap, which is a very good library for sniffing. So, I used this simple sniffer, which sniffs 5 packets: (It is written in C)

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include "hacking.h"

void pcap_fatal(const char *failed_in, const char *errbuf) {
     printf("Fatal Error in %s: %s\n", failed_in, errbuf);
     exit(1);
}

int main() {
    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
    const u_char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *device;
    pcap_t *pcap_handle;
    int i;

device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
if(device == NULL)
    pcap_fatal("pcap_lookupdev", errbuf);

printf("Sniffing on device %s\n", device);

pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);
if(pcap_handle == NULL)
    pcap_fatal("pcap_open_live", errbuf);

for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, &header);
    printf("Got a %d byte packet\n", header.len);
    dump(packet, header.len);
}

pcap_close(pcap_handle);

}
```

If you're wondering, yes I took it from a book (Hacking: The Art of Exploitation) and modified a little bit. The problem is, if I run this on Linux, it works perfectly, no problems. But if I run this on a Mac, it doesn't work and it doesn't capture any packet.

Can someone of you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it print any error messages? Are you sure you're listening on the right network device?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. It sniffs on 'en0' which is the right device.

Comment: you don't have access to /dev/bpf*, which is the sniffing device on Mac OS X. run it under sudo, and it may work for you.

Comment: The other problem is that there is a backing buffer for the pcap_open_live, and `pcap_next` may not return until the buffer has been filled. You should use a non-zero timeout when reading (e.g. 1000), and check if a packet got returned.

Comment: I am seeing the same strange behaviour on some Macs with my program (which also uses pcap_setfilter, started with sudo). On two Macs my program works fine, on two other (also latest OS, also all updates installed), I do not get any packets. Same code, different behavior. And what makes it even more strange: if I am running tcpdump in parallel, then tcdump dumps packets and my program starts receiving packets.

Comment: @WernerHenze: does your program pass 1 as the "promisc" argument to `pcap_open_live()`, or call `pcap_set_promisc()` after calling `pcap_create()` and before calling `pcap_activate()`?  If not, you're not running in promiscuous mode, so you will only see packets sent to or from your machine and broadcast/multicast packets; running tcpdump will, by default, put the interface into promiscuous mode, and *all* programs, including yours, might see third-party packets.

Comment: @GuyHarris I am not using promiscuous mode. I am only interested in packets that are targeted to my PC or to broadcast address. These packets should always be delivered to me. But I had a case where I only got them when tcpdump ran in parallel (and might have put the NIC into promiscuous mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a "Fatal Error in pcap_lookupdev" error message, then the problem is what Sascha said it was - you don't have permission to capture packets.  *If* you're getting that message, try running the program with `sudo`, or try, for example, changing the ownership of the /dev/bpf* devices to you (which you will need to do with `sudo`).  However, you're saying that "It sniffs on 'en0'", so presumably you're saying that because it's printing "Sniffing on device en0", in which case `pcap_lookupdev()` isn't failing.

If you're getting a "Fatal Error in pcap_open_live", that *might* also be a problem with permissions, but you almost certainly wouldn't get an error due to permissions there, as `pcap_lookupdev()` would already have failed.

If you're *not* getting a "Fatal Error in" error message, the problem is probably, as Petesh noted, that you specified 0 as the timeout.  If 0 is specified as the timeout, `pcap_loop()`, `pcap_dispatch()`, `pcap_next()`, and `pcap_next_ex()` can wait indefinitely before providing packets to the application; on some platforms, such as Linux and Solaris, it won't wait indefinitely, but on other platforms, such as *BSD and OS X, it could wait indefinitely.  Try a timeout of 1000, which is one second; that's what tcpdump does, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Petesh: For details, please check the manpage ("man pcap" in Terminal).

It states:

> Under BSD (this includes Mac OS X):
>
> ```
>           You must have read access to /dev/bpf* on systems that don't have a cloning
>           BPF device, or to /dev/bpf on systems that do.  On BSDs with a devfs  (this
>           includes  Mac OS X), this might involve more than just having somebody with
>           super-user access setting the ownership or permissions on the BPF devices -
>           it  might  involve  configuring  devfs  to set the ownership or permissions
>           every time the system is booted, if the system even supports  that;  if  it
>           doesn't  support  that,  you might have to find some other way to make that
>           happen at boot time.
> ```

Comment: You should add a note about the 'read timeout' - he's probably hitting that problem as well.

Comment: Actually, *you* should add that note - if you're answering his question (which your comments did), you should do so in an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tested code at 10.8.4 and worked with changing param to_ms (read timeout) to some non-zero value then started receiving packet.

Thanks for basic code. It saved my time.

Regards,
Anand Choubey